# Facebook Page Tab Inside Border

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, tabs

I am building a Facebook Page Tab. It links to a website that is being loaded into Facebook as an iFrame, following strictly along the lines of developing Facebook page tabs.

I notice though, on Facebook Stories (*a tab from the Facebook fan page*) they have a border around the loaded iframe.

It does not appear at the original source of the iframe, though. And I do not see an option for it in the Facebook Page Tab settings - it also appears to match the *`style/css`* of the facebook iframe.

**My question is:** How can I have a border surrounding an iframe loaded in another page (this instance, Facebook Page Tab) that does not appear at the original source of the webpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook stories tab you refer to doesn't have a border on the iframe. The border is set on the body with css.
If you check the source of the tab : https://www.facebookstories.com/tab/
You will see the border next to the scrollbar.

I hope this answers you question :)

Comment: That absolutely worked! 
I added in my css: 

body: border:1px solid #CCC;